# How to search and create a json directory using python for specified file types only

Tags: python, json, directory

I am trying to create a json directory tree of a directory that exist on my computer. but I would only like to include the type, name, and path for .exe, .bat, .cmd files. I have found this online and it works to create an entire directory but I would like to clean it up for only the file types.

I have tried using "good words", but this destroys my json syntax and leaves a lot of open space

```
def path_hierarchy(path):
    hierarchy = {
        'type': 'folder',
        'name': os.path.basename(path),
        'path': path,
    }

try:
    hierarchy['children'] = [
        path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
        for contents in os.listdir(path)
    ]
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
        raise
    hierarchy['type'] = 'file'

return hierarchy


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        directory = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        directory = "."

    hierarchy = path_hierarchy(r"\mypath\") 
    with open('myjson.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(hierarchy, outfile, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

good_words = ['.exe', '.cmd', '.bat','},','{','[',']']   

with open('myjson.json') as oldfile, open('myjsonfixed.json', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if any(good_word in line for good_word in good_words):
            newfile.write(line.replace(dontwant,want))
```

Comment: Don't use string processing on JSON, parse it with `json.load()` and operate on the objects.

Comment: Why don't you filter the file extensions when you're creating the directory instead of after you write the file?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. `try` should be indented inside `path_hierarchy()`.

Comment: yes I know my indentation is wrong here on stack overflow but it is correct in my actual code sorry it was hard to format correctly in this forum. I will look into this thank you

Comment: Paste the code with correct indentation, and put 3 backticks before and after the code as I did.